How to deploy Excel Javascript Add-in with a custom function added parameters
I have a JavaScript Excel Add-in deployed in production, being used by a number of customers. The Add-in includes a custom function. I have added new optional parameters to the function but when I deploy this version Excel does not recognize the updated function.
What is the correct process to deploy this kind of change? It is a feature update that does not require a change to the manifest but I am not sure how to get Excel to recognize the updated function.
Clearing the Add-in cache or re-installing the Add-in will resolve the issue but I cannot expect my customers to do that.

Please raise this issue on the office-js repo.
